# GC_minor issue on Blazor html5 canvas and c# timer

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, canvas, timer, blazor

```
private Canvas2DContext _context;

protected BECanvasComponent _canvasReference;

protected override async Task OnAfterRenderAsync(bool firstRender)
{
    this._context = await this._canvasReference.CreateCanvas2DAsync();

    var centerX = _canvasReference.Width / 2;
    var centerY = _canvasReference.Height / 2;
    var radius = 80;
    var full = radius * 2;
    var amount = 0.0;
    var amountToIncrease = 0.1;

    var aTimer = new Timer(500);

    async void draw(Object source, ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
        await this._context.BeginBatchAsync();
        await this._context.ArcAsync(centerX, centerY, radius, 0, amount * Math.PI, false);
        await this._context.SetFillStyleAsync("#13a8a4");
        await this._context.FillAsync();
        await this._context.SetLineWidthAsync(10);
        await this._context.SetStrokeStyleAsync("#000000");
        await this._context.StrokeAsync();
        amount += amountToIncrease;
        if (amount > full) amount = 0; // restart

        await InvokeAsync(() =>
        {
            StateHasChanged();
        });          
    }

    aTimer.Elapsed += draw;
    aTimer.AutoReset = true;
    aTimer.Enabled = true;
}
```

I want to implement circle animation on htm5 canvas. I use html5 canvas extension for blazor. what am I doing wrong? On blazor server that works, on web assembly, I got GC_minor in developer tools

Comment: It may be related to the fact that you do not execute your code within an if block like that: if( firstRender) {your code should be here, and it would execute only once } otherwise, your code would execute whenever the OnAfterRenderAsync is executed

Answer (score 1):

I could reproduce the same issue:

1. The above comment by @[enet](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6152891/enet) is right. You should at least check whether the `firstRender` is true and avoid attaching the `draw()` function to a new timer each time.
2. Apart from that, you should create a `Timer` as a separated field. And don't forget to **DISPOSE** the `Timer` when the component is disposed.
3. Finally, there's another issue within your code: You didn't invoke the `_context.EndBatchAsync()`. As a result, it will **NOT** draw anything.

To fix the above issues, change your code as below:

```
...
@implements IDisposable    @* A Timer is a resource that should be disposed *@

...


@code{

    private Canvas2DContext _context;

    protected BECanvasComponent _canvasReference;

    private Timer _aTimer = new Timer(500);

    public void Dispose()
    {
        this._aTimer.Dispose();
    }


    protected override async Task OnAfterRenderAsync(bool firstRender)
    {
        this._context = await this._canvasReference.CreateCanvas2DAsync();

        var centerX = _canvasReference.Width / 2;
        var centerY = _canvasReference.Height / 2;
        var radius = 80;
        var full = radius * 2;
        var amount = 0.0;
        var amountToIncrease = 0.1;
        if(firstRender)
        {
            // you might decide to put the above `var amount = 0.0; ...` here too, it depends on your needs
            this._aTimer.Elapsed += draw;
            this._aTimer.AutoReset = true;
            this._aTimer.Enabled = true;
        }
        async void draw(Object source, ElapsedEventArgs e)
        {
            await this._context.BeginBatchAsync();
            await this._context.ArcAsync(centerX, centerY, radius, 0, amount * Math.PI, false);
            await this._context.SetFillStyleAsync("#13a8a4");
            await this._context.FillAsync();
            await this._context.SetLineWidthAsync(10);
            await this._context.SetStrokeStyleAsync("#000000");
            await this._context.StrokeAsync();

            await this._context.EndBatchAsync();  // add this line !
            amount += amountToIncrease;
            if (amount > full) amount = 0; // restart

            await InvokeAsync(() => { StateHasChanged(); });          
        }

    }
}
```

#### Demo

[image]

---

**[Edit]**

> i am wondering why there are those lines inside the circle?

Those lines are the part of closed path last time. Actually, there's a `beginPath` api that starts a new path by emptying the list of sub-paths.( See [docs on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/beginPath)). In other words, if you don't need them, invoke `_context.BeginPathAsync();` :

```
await this._context.BeginBatchAsync();
await this._context.BeginPathAsync(); // add this line
await this._context.ArcAsync(centerX, centerY, radius, 0, amount * Math.PI, false);
...
```

**[Demo2] :**

[image]

---

By the way, you don't have to notify the state has changed here (because you didn't change the component state):

```
//await InvokeAsync(() => { StateHasChanged(); });
```

Comment: super :). and i am wondering why there are those lines inside the circle?

Comment: @MariusJurjonas I've edited my answer to show you the reason and how to avoid that lines. Please check it :)